# Enabling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing with Auth0 for Angular2 authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, cross-domain, auth0

I'm trying to create user authentication via Auth0. I've followed the guide written on their website but I find that authentication fails with a message logged to the console saying **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is not enabled**.

My `auth.service.ts` class:

```
export class AuthService {
  // Configure Auth0
  auth0 = new Auth0({
    domain: myConfig.domain,
    clientID: myConfig.clientID,
    callbackOnLocationHash: true,
    callbackURL: myConfig.callbackURL,
  });

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    var result = this.auth0.parseHash(window.location.hash);

    if (result && result.idToken) {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', result.idToken);
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    } else if (result && result.error) {
      alert('error: ' + result.error);
    }
  }

  public login(username: string, password: string) {
    this.auth0.login({
      connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
      responseType: 'token',
      email: username,
      password: password,
    }, function(err: any) { if (err) alert("something went wrong: " + err.message); });
  };
}
```

I believe I need to add something to the headers, possibly: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.auth0.com*`, but where would I need to add this and in what format should it be input?

The full error message is the following:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://[mydomain]/usernamepassword/login. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). HTTP status code: 400.

I am currently using the 'lite' Angular2 development server library/process.

The domain name has been added to both the callback and CORS whitelists using the Auth0 dashboard, in the following format:

```
http://*.[mydomain]*
```

I would attempt to add `https://*.[mydomain]*` to the list and  set an automatic redirect to `https://` to see if this would help, but the website doesn't seem to like being accessed via https and throws the following error when I attempt to do so:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> The connection to www.[mydomain]:3004 was interrupted while the page was loading.

Perhaps because I haven't got an SSL certificate??

Comment: What's the error message? Are you sure that your server is configured to response with CORS headers? The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is something that is returned from the server and not sent from the client.

Comment: @NitzanTomer probably not? It's just a Linode with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I haven't done anything specific to enable CORS, so I guess it's not enabled...? I'm using the lite server process from the Angular2 docs at the moment...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in Angular2 development mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767093/setting-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-angular2-development-mode)

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting is from an Auth0 API (`https://[mydomain]/usernamepassword/login`) so the problem is not your server **not** returning the appropriate CORS headers, it's the Auth0 server that due to security will not allow CORS requests **unless you configure a whitelist of origins**.

This means that if you want to interact with Auth0 API's from within the browser you need to configure it in such way that it recognizes your client application origin and adds the necessary CORS headers to make it work.

You can do this by adding the correct origin to the **Allowed Origins (CORS)** settings available in the [client application settings](https://auth0.com/docs/clients#client-settings) of your Auth0 Dashboard.

Comment: Ah. I was attempting to use Auth0 to allow website users to create user account while I'm in the process of implementing a proper backend. Is Auth0 not the correct solution for this perhaps? Obviously I can't expect all users to change their client browser settings in order to login to my site and create use accounts...

Comment: Auth0 is the ideal solution if you want to delegate your authentication/authorization logic so that you can focus on your apps' business value. About the change: **It's not user client browser settings**; you and **just you** needs to update the setting Allowed Origins (CORS)  of the client application in the [Auth0 Dashboard](https://manage.auth0.com/#/). Also check the link I added in the answer.

Comment: I made sure the domain was added to the CORS list in the Auth0 dashboard but I'm still getting the same error. Going to look through the link in your answer, see if I can work out anything more from there.

Comment: yes it works but we also have to specify port number. For eg; http://localhost:4200

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may be having this issue still, but added your URL to the CORS settings in your Client Settings as Joao suggested... make sure that your configuration is using the correct Client ID. If you copy the code from the Quick Start, it defaults to the "Default App" client ID, so you need to change that to the correct client's ID for your CORS settings to take hold